# How to compute the inner integral with quad?

Tags: python, integral, quad

I am reading [the paper by Floris](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=96020)​ and try to compute the numerical value of the normalization constant `C_I` from eq. (20).

From the eqution

[image: 2]]

and property of transition probability density function (PDF)
[image], the normalization constant is:

[image]

In my case, `m_1(x)=-(a*x+b*x**3)`, `m_2(x)= c+ sigma**2*x`,
`a=1.0, b=0.5, c = 1.0, sigma = 1.0`.

I have used the [quad()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html) function in my attempt for the inner integral:

```
import numpy as np
exp = np.exp
inf = np.inf
log  = np.log
sqrt = np.sqrt

from scipy.integrate import quad

a = 1.0;  b = 0.5; c = 1.0; sigma = 1.0

tspan = np.linspace(0.0, 2.5, 5001)
x0 = 0.1

def m_1(x, t):
  return -(a*x + b*x**3)

def m_2(x, t):
  return (c + sigma**2 * x)

def inner_integrand(x0, x, t):
  return 2 * m_1(x,t) / m_2(x,t)**2

inner = quad(inner_integrand, -inf, inf, args=(x0, tspan))[0]
print('inner_integrand=', inner)
# inner_integrand= -1.693896469019819
```

and I have obtained the result `inner_integrand= 0.33223140495839776`.

When I have used the [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%202*%28-%28x%2Bx%5E3%2F2%29%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%5E2%20dx%20from%20x%3D-inf%20to%20inf), the result is 'integral does not convergence'

**Question.** How to compute the inner integral?

Comment: I don't understand this mathematical stuff, but I understand that `quad` is passing to `integrand` three values: first value with meaning that I don't understand, second value `x0` and third value `tspan`. `integrand` (that you deleted from example) was like: `integrand(x, t)`, but it should be `integrand(value_passing_from_quad, x, t)`.

Comment: I have deleted the integrand when edited the post, now it was returned.

Answer (score 1):

integrand will be called with some `x` selected by the algorithm *and* your extra arguments after that.

Your call `quad(integrand, -inf, inf, args=(x0, tspan))` will make calls like `integrand(x, x0, tspan)` and while I do not know what integrand is, this does not seem to be what the function expects.

Comment: I have deleted the integrand when edited the post, now it was returned.